# Check if user can edit node with certain ID

Tags: 7, users

I need to know a function or a way to find out if a user can edit a certain node.

For example I have the nid 200 and the user foo has logged in, I want to check if he is able to edit node/200.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7) to do this:

```
$node = node_load(123);
$account = user_load(456);

if (node_access("update", $node, $account) === TRUE) {
  do_something_awesome();
}
```

If you look at the source for `node_access`, you will see that the `$node` argument can also be a `$nid`.  This is how the path for the edit pages get checked (see the 'node/%node/edit' entry in [`node_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then it seems like I'm doing something wrong. http://pastebin.com/tjcWbZNc - only as admin I'll get the right output. But as a certain user, I can edit the node, but node_access won't return true.

Comment: Okay, it only works if the permission "Bypass content access control" is set.

Comment: well... I think it's because of a plugin I've installed - I found another way to reach my goal... but I think your way is the normal way. Thanks

Comment: If you dont use $the account parameter, it defaults to the current user.